# Jquery draggable inside-out containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

instead of having the containment of the draggable element around it, how can I have it inside it? So you can drag the element anywhere as long as the edges of it do not collide with the element inside of it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use the `drag` event and update the `ui.position` or `ui.offset` fields, to manually constrain the item.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lingo/GKpC5) is a jsfiddle to illustrate the concept, although this doesn't fully implement what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

You could fake it by making a real containing component that restricts your draggable element as if it is constrained by the smaller element. You would just have to make the dimensions of the real container like this:

```
Container.height = (Draggable.height - Restrict.height) + Draggable.height
Container.width = (Draggable.width - Restrict.width) + Draggable.width
```

[image: Diagram]

Then, you would also need to counter the dragging motion so that the contained restriction element doesn't seem to move when the draggable element moves. Either that or the immobile section could be a floating div.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you!

Comment: TJ, your code is very basic, yes it uses little code, but if the restrict would change size, you would have to change the css. That's not really practical is it?

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov I added an answer that addresses this question.  It's not practical if you plan on reusing the code at all, but I find it more elegant if you just need it for one use case.

Comment: Ok you're right. I guess I didn't imply that I want to reuse the code :) But it's good for others

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is interested in this, using Rusty's code and logic [here's a JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/umL7Y).

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @RustyTheBoyRobot's answer you could also accomplish in CSS alone if you have known dimensions of your draggable.

**Live Example** - jsbin.com/agovex

The obvious downside of this is if you want to reuse this in multiple situations it's not going to work because the values are hardcoded in CSS.  But if you only need it for one thing with known dimensions I find the CSS only approach simple and elegant.  There's only one line of JavaScript to create the draggable.